# Why does my Google chart not appear in Fusion Tables infowindow?

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google's Chart API to display a chart in an infowindow.

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?classic=true&docid=1z614mo0DPw19PX00IFsW7g0S-yilCmUTQaKLjiw

I've created the following img using the chart wizard:

[image: Tickets issued in {Road}]

What I want to do is tweak it so I can pass in parameters, but it doesn't appear.

Here's the code of the original (which appears above):

```
<img src="//chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxl=1:|2008|2009|2010|2011&chxr=0,0,5000|1,-5,100&chxs=0,676767,10.5,0.333,lt,676767|1,676767,11.833,0.167,l,676767&chxt=y,x&chs=300x173&cht=lxy&chds=0,5000,0,5000&chd=t:-1|111,122,1685,4699&chdlp=b&chls=3&chma=|2,4&chtt=Tickets+issued+in+xxx&chts=676767,11.833" width="300" height="173" alt="Tickets issued in {Road}" />
```

Here's my effort, which doesn't work.

```
<img src="//chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxl=1:|2008|2009|2010|2011&chxr=0,0,5000|1,-5,100&chxs=0,676767,10.5,0.333,lt,676767|1,676767,11.833,0.167,l,676767&chxt=y,x&chs=300x173&cht=lxy&chds=0,5000,0,5000&chd=t:|{2008},{2009},{2010},{2011}&chdlp=b&chls=3&chma=|2,4&chtt=Tickets+issued+in+{Road}&chts=676767,11.833" width="300" height="173" alt="Tickets issued in {Road}" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work was because there wasn't an 'http:' at the start of the img src bit.